# MySQLRoleProvider in MVC4

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I use MySQLRoleProvider in MVC4?
MySQLProfileProvider and MySQLMembershipProvider works fine, but Roles.IsUserInRole("myRole") doesnt work in VS2012 MVC4! Always returns Fasle.

```
<profile defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySQLProfileProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="\" description="" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" writeExceptionsToEventLog="True" autogenerateschema="True" enableExpireCallback="False" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySQLRoleProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="\" description="MyRoles description lwt" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" writeExceptionsToEventLog="True" autogenerateschema="True" enableExpireCallback="False" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <remove name="MySQLMembershipProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="/" description="MySQL default application" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" writeExceptionsToEventLog="True" autogenerateschema="True" enableExpireCallback="False" enablePasswordRetrieval="False" enablePasswordReset="True" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="True" requiresUniqueEmail="False" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your not crazy, this is currently a verified bug:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75397

it drove me crazy as well until I decompiled the dll to see the implementation.

Comment: fixed as of MySql .NET Connector 6.9.6